# How to edit the URL in hyperlink in mass?

Tags: microsoft-word, url, microsoft-onenote, hyperlink, url-rewriting

Say I have a text like this:

> [Link 1](http://example.com/text_to_change/fixed_text)
>   [Link 2](http://example.com/text_to_change/fixed_text)
>   [Link 3](http://example.com/text_to_change/fixed_text)

Notice that all the URLs has this format `http://example.com/text_to_change/fixed_text`

Now I want to edit them to this:

> [Link 1](http://example.com/changed_text/fixed_text)
>   [Link 2](http://example.com/changed_text/fixed_text)
>   [Link 3](http://example.com/changed_text/fixed_text)

With the new URLs are `http://example.com/changed_text/fixed_text`

So in short, I want to edit the URLs in mass without changing the text to display. In Word or OneNote, is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Word, press <kbd>Alt+F9</kbd> to open field code, then press <kbd>Ctrl+H</kbd> to mass editing the URLs, then <kbd>Alt+F9</kbd> again